# Launch project symfony in browser

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have launched my Symfony project in browser but I have this problem in `error.log`

> [:error] [pid 4789] [client ::1:39684] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/var/www...', NULL, NULL, Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOSqlite/Driver.php(60): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('sqlite:/var/www...', NULL, NULL, Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver->connect(Array, NULL, NULL, Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(1365): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()\n#4 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal/src/Jackalope/Transport/DoctrineDBAL/Client.php(2619): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()\n#5 /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jack in /var/www/html/ensoSteps/vendor/jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal/src/Jackalope/Transport/DoctrineDBAL/Client.php on line 460

Help me please for solved this problem.

Comment: Your PHP installation does not have driver for SQLite. Particular installation procedure depends of your operating system.

Comment: for Ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Comment: Try putting part of your error to google. I guarantee you that it'll be quicker to fix than asking here.

Comment: in parameters.yml : database_driver: pdo_mysql but when i tape command sudo apt-get install php-mysql , ihave this message "ackage php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate", i use php 5.6

Comment: alo alo help me please

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

check **parameters.yml** file - 

parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql